# Like con los países que tengan seis caracteres en su nombre

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tratando de hacer un filtro con los países que tengan 6 caracteres un su nombre

Realice estos intentos:

1) Sub consulta

```
SELECT c.name FROM country as c
WHERE c.name = (SELECT LEN(Name) FROM country )
```

2)

```
SELECT c.name FROM country as c
WHERE c.name LIKE '______'
```

3)

```
SELECT Name, LEN(Name) AS LONG FROM country WHERE (((LEN(Name))=6))
```

Funcionandome la ultima sentencia (3)
Hay alguna otra forma de obtener esto?
La opción 2 creo también es correcta, pero no me funciono.

Si pudieran ayudarme a aclarar las dudas se lo agradecería.

Saludos

DS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La primera forma que has expuesto dice dame todos los nombres de países donde el nombre sea igual a: Dame la longitud de la columna nombre de países. Esto te tiene que dar error.

La opción 2 es correcta, y tiene que funcionar

```
Declare @COUNTRY table
                       (
                       id   int
                     , Name varchar(100)
                       );

insert into @COUNTRY(id
                   , Name)
values
       ( 1, 'Costa de Marfil' ),
       ( 2, 'Egipto' ),
       ( 3, 'Eritrea' ),
       ( 4, 'Etiopía' ),
       ( 5, 'Bután' );

Declare @COUNTRY table
                       (
                       id   int
                     , Name varchar(100)
                       );

insert into @COUNTRY(id
                   , Name)
values
       ( 1, 'Costa de Marfil' ),
       ( 2, 'Egipto' ),
       ( 3, 'Eritrea' ),
       ( 4, 'Etiopía' ),
       ( 5, 'Bután' );

select Name
       from @COUNTRY
       where len(name) = 6;

select name
       from @COUNTRY
       where name like '______';

select name
       from @COUNTRY
       where name like '[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]';
```

[image: Solución]

Cuando creas que algo no te funciona para aplicar en el where, la opción más fácil es quitarlo de restricción, y ponerlo en una columna como parte de la select, y así sabes el motivo. En el caso de like es complicado, porque no se puede usar en la select, pero siempre puedes hacer una pequeña trampa.

Lo declaras como una subconsulta, e igualas el id de la subconsulta, contra el id de la consulta exterior.

```
Declare @COUNTRY table
                       (
                       id   int
                     , Name varchar(100)
                       );

insert into @COUNTRY(id
                   , Name)
values
       ( 1, 'Costa de Marfil' ),
       ( 2, 'Egipto' ),
       ( 3, 'Eritrea' ),
       ( 4, 'Etiopía' ),
       ( 5, 'Bután' );

select id
     , Name
     , (
         select name
                from @COUNTRY AS d
                where name like '______' and d.id = t.id
       )
       from @COUNTRY AS t;
```

[image: Solución]

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas proporcionadas y las aclaraciones realizadas.
La opción dos, porque no me mostrara los resultados, si es correcta la sentencia?

Comment: ¿Es posible que como no se puede diferenciar el número de subrayados, hubiese 5 o 7 en vez de seis?

Comment: En todo caso me devolveria los paises que tuvieran 5 o 7 caracteres, no es así?

Comment: Pude observar que los campos despues de el ultimo caracter tienen espacios, pudiese ir por ahi el problema?

Comment: Si, para like '_x6' los espacios son también un carácter. En ese escenario puedes aplicar Select name from country where trim(name) like '______' o si no dispones de trim, lo mismo con ltrim(rtrim(name))